# How to properly get console_scripts install_scripts directory?

Tags: python, pip, package, setuptools, setup.py

I splitted a complex Python script into a package for easier maintenance and distribution. I created a fresh `setup.py` (using `setupmeta`) with a `console_scripts` entry point and the package structure. So far, so good.

I had some unusual requirements, though:

- the package is to always be installed in a `virtualenvwrapper` project,
- so the script is installed in the `${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin` directory...
- ...and I *must* create a symlink targetting the script in the `${VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_PATH}/bin` directory. (don't ask... :-)

For that purpose:

1. I added a `locate_project_path()` function in the `setup.py` script,
2. added the following `install_and_symlink_script` subclass to `setuptools.command.install.install`:

   ```py
   class install_and_symlink_script(install):                           
       """Do normal install, but symlink script to project directory""" 

       def run(self):                                                   
           install.run(self)                                            

           script_path = os.path.join(self.install_scripts, SCRIPT_NAME)
           project_path = locate_project_path()                         
           symlink_path = os.path.join(project_path, "bin", SCRIPT_NAME)

           print("creating %s script symlink" % SCRIPT_NAME)            

           if os.path.exists(symlink_path):                             
               print("removing existing symlink %s" % symlink_path)     
               os.unlink(symlink_path)                                  

           print("creating symlink from %s to %s" % (                   
               symlink_path, script_path))                              
           os.symlink(script_path, symlink_path)
   ```
3. and configured `setup()` this way:

   ```py
   setup(
       ...
       entry_points={
           "console_scripts": ["%s=myscriptpackage.cli:main" % SCRIPT_NAME],
       },
       cmdclass={
           "install": install_and_symlink_script,
       },
       ...
   )
   ```

When performing a local `python ./setup.py install`, the package installation and symlink creation works perfectly.

But when performing a `pip install git+ssh://.../myscriptpackage.git`, it fails:

```
...
running install_egg_info
Copying src/myscriptpackage.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/myscriptpackage-0.4.0-py2.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
creating my-script script symlink
creating symlink from /path/to/virtualenvwrapper/project/bin/my-script to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/myscriptpackage-0.4.0.data/scripts/my-script
error: [Errno 17] File exists
error
Failed building wheel for myscriptpackage
...
```

Meaning, when installing through `pip` instead of a `python ./setup.py install`:

1. it fails to detect an existing symlink, and unlink it.
2. the `install_and_symlink_script.install_scripts` variable point to the script *inside* the build directory instead of the final scripts installation directory... :-|

So... do you know a way to get the correct scripts installation directory, compatible with both a `pip install` and a `python ./setup.py install` ?

(Btw, I'm using python 2.7.13, setuptools 39.1.0, virtualenvwrapper 4.8.2 under Debian 9)

## UPDATE 1

I knew the `error: [Errno 17] File exists` issue was coming from the `os.path.exists(symlink_path)` call.

I just understood why: if a symlink was created from a previous install, that symlink is broken during the new install. `os.path.exists` returns False for a broken symlink. OTOH, `os.path.lexists` returns True if the symlink exists, broken or not...

Comment: could you just run python setup.py .. on after going to the path where setup.py lies.

Comment: When running a `python ./setup.py install`, the script is *correctly* installed in the `${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/` directory and the symlink created in the `${PROJECT_PATH}/bin/` directory. (the `setuptools.command.install.install.install_scripts` variable is set to `${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/` directory). With a `pip install`, the `setuptools.command.install.install.install_scripts` variable is set to a directory inside a wheel, in the build directory, *not* the to `${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/` directory.
I need a `pip install` to work correctly, as my package has to be included in a `requirements.txt` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to consistently get the scripts installation directory when installing through a `python ./setup.py install` or through a `pip install`, using the `wheel.paths.get_install_paths()` function.

My setuptools custom install command is now:

```
...
from wheel.paths import get_install_paths

__title__ = "myscriptpackage"
...

class install_and_symlink_script(install):                            
    """Do normal install, but symlink script to project directory"""  

    def run(self):                                                    
        install.run(self)                                             

        wheel_install_paths = get_install_paths(__title__)            
        script_path = os.path.join(wheel_install_paths['scripts'], SCRIPT_NAME)                  
        # instead of: script_path = os.path.join(self.install_scripts, SCRIPT_NAME)

        project_path = locate_project_path()                          
        symlink_path = os.path.join(project_path, "bin", SCRIPT_NAME) 

        print("creating %s script symlink" % SCRIPT_NAME)             

        if os.path.lexists(symlink_path):                             
            print("removing existing symlink %s" % symlink_path)      
            os.unlink(symlink_path)                                   

        print("creating symlink from %s to %s" % (                    
            symlink_path, script_path))                               
        os.symlink(script_path, symlink_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for this excellent Q&A. Would you mind sharing a sample `setup.py` that works in Python 3? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting about the admin rights on your machine could be an issues.
could you please try running cmd in admin mode then after going to the path where setup.py lies could you just run:

```
 python setup.py
```

Next it it is trying to create a symlink in the folder

```
build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/myscriptpackage-0.4.0.data/scripts/my-script

I request you to try making symlink on your own in this folder.
```

If this is not the solution then there is some version mismatch.
Just let me know if it helps

Comment: The entire application and the packages are installed in an isolated `virtualenv`, not at system-level, thus I should not use any admin commands.